# How to run plotly package with R in Jupyter notebook from Google Colab

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, jupyter, visualization

i'm R users

I have tried to run the R code in Jupyter notebook from Google Colab.
But the plotly package doesn't work despite of the well processing in Rmarkdown in Rstudio.

Here is my problem.
If I run like as

X =c(1:3)
Y=c(2:6)
plot(X,Y)

It works and shows the plot in below

But, When I run the code with ggplot2 or plotly package like

gg<- ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_point()

ggplotly(gg)

It doesn't work.
Please to tell me what is wrong.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: First, thanks for your consideration. The screen doesn't show me any thing though the code is well recognised

Answer (score 1):

There's an unresolved issue with `plotly` in a Jupyter notebook with the `IRKernel`. If you call it twice, you should see the plot.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(X =c(1:5),  Y=c(2:6) )
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_point()
ggplotly(gg)
ggplotly(gg)
```

This may not be good enough for you but if it works, it's a start.[image]

Comment: Many thanks. The purpose i try to solve this problem is I wanna use crosstalk package to make an interactive click.